# Capistrano Rails deploy Passenger error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, passenger, bundle-install

I deployed my Rails application to my local IP address. After the successful deployment, when I opened the page in browser, I get the following error. I have been stuck with the following issue for sometime.

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

    bundle install

If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the deploy user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize'
  /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
  ...
```

I verified [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663498/rails-phusion-passenger-error-after-updates) and tried the following things.

> I did `bundle install` multiple times as `deploy` user.
>
> I had 2 versions of rake installed, `11.1.2` and `10.4.2`. I purged `11.1.2`. Made sure this version is not there anywhere.
>
> I see 2 ruby versions. 1.9.3 and 2.2.2. Not sure if this is the issue. I did not manually install 1.9.3. But I see the folders `/usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448` and `/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448`. When I tried to remove 1.9.3, using `sudo apt-get remove ruby 1.9.3` I got the following result. In the end, I **did not** remove it as it was trying to remove `passenger` itself.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-xslt-dev-9.1.1-9b3da' for regex '1.9.3'
Note, selecting 'ruby1.9.3' for regex '1.9.3'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-xslt-prof-9.1.1-9b3da' for regex '1.9.3'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-xslt-dev' instead of 'libghc-hxt-xslt-dev-9.1.1-9b3da'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-xslt-prof' instead of 'libghc-hxt-xslt-prof-9.1.1-9b3da'
Package 'ruby1.9.3' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libruby2.1 passenger passenger-dev ri ruby ruby-dev ruby-full ruby-rack ruby2.1 ruby2.1-dev
```

Any help related to this issue is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I see files related to rake 11.1.2 still

```
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/rake-11.1.2.gem
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/specifications/rake-11.1.2.gemspec
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/cache/rake-11.1.2.gem
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/specifications/rake-11.1.2.gemspec
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/cache/rake-11.1.2.gem
/home/deploy/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.1.2
/home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/doc/rake-11.1.2
/home/deploy/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-11.1.2.gemspec
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/doc/rake-11.1.2
```

Could this be the problem?

I share the Ruby Environment details below.

```
RubyGems Environment:
   RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
   RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]
   INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2
   RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
   EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin
   SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/deploy/.gem/specs
   SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/etc
   RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     ruby
     x86_64-linux
   GEM PATHS:
     /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2
     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
   GEM CONFIGURATION:
     :update_sources => true
     :verbose => true
     :backtrace => false
     :bulk_threshold => 1000
   REMOTE SOURCES:
     https://rubygems.org/
   SHELL PATH:
     /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin
     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bin
     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     /usr/local/sbin
     /usr/local/bin
     /usr/sbin
     /usr/bin
     /sbin
     /bin
     /usr/games
     /usr/local/games
```

Nginx conf file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is as follows.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Nginx sites-enabled default file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name 192.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    prelive;
    root         /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting the rails server?

Comment: @emaillenin for passenger it is not needed.

Comment: Nop.. my env is called `prelive`. It is pointing to my ip address. So I am doing `cap prelive deploy`

Comment: @PhilipJohn share the nginx config please. Also provide information about ruby env. e.g. version manager, `gem env` command.

Comment: @Зелёный Updated with nginx conf and ruby env details

Comment: I can't find the `root` directive to your rails app in the nginx config, it can be a problem, because passenger cant find your app. Is anything else in the `conf.d/` or `sites-enabled/` ?

Comment: @Зелёный Yeah.. in `sites-enabled/default` there is the `root` directive. Updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113406/discussion-between--and-philip-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did the following three steps and it started working. These are from the comments of [Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9). Seems like I had to restart the machine or something for the changes to reflect. I am not sure.

1. Checked `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and make sure the value for `passenger_ruby` is the same as output of `which ruby` command
2. Check if rake version is `10.4.2` by executing `rake --version`. Else purge all rake and install rake 10.4.2
3. `bundle install`

After doing these, I restarted the machine and did `cap prelive deploy` and the application was up.